# Fetch one document per condition in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this somewhat complex ElasticSearch query that has 5 conditions, and I need 1 document per condition and additionally 1 document can't be returned for two conditions.

So I tried two different approaches

First Multi search

```
GET /products/_msearch
{}
{"query": {"function_score":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{ "match":
{"category":"1"}},"must_not":[{"ids":{"values": 
["7DhlWxCY4oQyo8884AIS4Y","3fy0uSuMROSoCQueGA2uO4"]}}]}}, 
"random_score":{"seed":1376718000}}},"from":0,"size":1}
{}
{"query": {"function_score":{"query":{"bool":{"must":{ "match":
{"category":"2"}},"must_not":[{"ids":{"values": 
["7DhlWxCY4oQyo8884AIS4Y","3fy0uSuMROSoCQueGA2uO4"]}}]}}, 
"random_score":{"seed":1376718000}}},"from":0,"size":1}
```

So I need to query 1 product from category 1 and category 2 each, but I need to filter all products I already bought, and additionally product can be in both category 1 and 2, but I don't want to receive same product from both queries.

But this query I've written can actually return same product from both categories.

Second approach I took was that I tried ordinary search like this

```
GET /products/product/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":{ 
                "bool": {
                    "must":[ 
                        { "match":{"category":"1"} } ,
                        { "match":{"category":"2"} }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "must_not": [{
                "ids": {
                    "values": [
                        "7DhlWxCY4oQyo8884AIS4Y", 
                        "3fy0uSuMROSoCQueGA2uO4"
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

But this will of course return only products in both categories.

So any idea how to accomplish my case

- One unique product from each category excluding products one already bought

According to comment by `Val` I came up with this query

```
GET /products/product/_search
{
  "aggs" : {
    "categories" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "category" },
      "aggs": {
            "top": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size" : 1
                }
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this just returns everything so I guess I'm doing something very wrong, but I just started working with ES, and I'm not sure what

Comment: How about using a `terms` aggregation on the `category` field and then a `top_hits` sub-aggregation with size=1 ? That would probably achieve what you want.

Comment: Can you give me reference in docs or example please?

Comment: terms agg: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html + top_hits agg: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: I've updated question, but I'm really not sure if what I did even makes sense since I'm very new to this. I only started working with ES two days ago

Comment: Add size:0 at the top level + your initial query as well and then look into what you get in the `aggregations` section of the response.

Comment: Yes. It actually works, but it still can return same products in two separate buckets

Comment: Couldn't you return N+1 rows and then just take the first row from each that is not in the list of results?

Comment: Hi Filip. I haven't figured out how to do this. Can you give link to some example or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "myAgg": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "cat1": {
            "term": {
              "category": "1"
            }
          },
          "cat2": {
            "term": {
              "category": "2"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you will get two buckets, one for each category with exactly one hit for each.

If you would like to expand your search for every category and also exclude by specific field, try this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "myAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bool_agg": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "terms": {
                  "ids": [
                    "7DhlWxCY4oQyo8884AIS4Y",
                    "3fy0uSuMROSoCQueGA2uO4"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "top": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you'll get bucket for each category with one top hit of the relevant search.

Comment: Thanks. The first one still gives duplicates. So I get product with same ID in 2 buckets, and second one gives me an error `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [levels] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory`

Comment: Well, I guess it has something to do with your mapping and the way documents are being indexed in your cluster. I suggest you to read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) and [this](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/issues/643)